# Convert object to int (Python pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with following data :

`df['Exp'] = ['10+ years', '8 years', '6 years', '7 years', '5 years','1 year', '< 1 year', '4 years', '3 years', '2 years', '9 years']`

I need to convert this column to int format.

How can I do it?

Thanks !

Comment: `pd.factorize()`?

Comment: Do you need to differentiate between  `1 year`, `< 1 year` or should they both be 1?

Comment: no need, just 1 <year = 1, 2 = 2 years, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Exp': ['10+ years', '8 years', '6 years', '7 years', '5 years','1 year', '< 1 year', '4 years', '3 years', '2 years', '9 years']})    
df['Exp'] = df['Exp'].replace('\D','', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Output

```
Exp
0   10
1   8
2   6
3   7
4   5
5   1
6   1
7   4
8   3
9   2
10  9
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
df.Exp.str.extract('(\d{1,})').astype(int)
```

For clarity the `\d` grabs any numeric string and the `{1,}` ensures there is at least one.

EDIT: (Sorry didn't read the question right) To convert it you could do:

```
df['Exp'] = df.Exp.str.extract('(\d{1,})').astype(int)
```

Assuming you want empty rows filled with minus one then you could do:

```
df['Exp'] = df.Exp.str.extract('(\d{1,})').fillna(-1).astype(int)
```

Comment: when i tried this method the following error pop up: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @Nlk What is the desired outcome when there is an empty row?

Comment: well, there are about 1000 rows with the data, so for each row need to be converted to proper int. like [1,1,2,10,0.....etc]

Comment: Makes sense, I updated the answer to fill blank rows with -1.